# Can't add a new keyword to Python

Tags: python, windows, language-specifications

I tried to add a new keyword (a new flow statement) to Python, by following [this blog post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/30/python-internals-adding-a-new-statement-to-python/) and [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0306/). I'm pretty sure I've added what I needed to add to the right places, according to the PEP that I've mentioned. These are the files that I've modified:

```
Grammar/Grammar
Parser/Python.asdl
Python/ast.c
Python/Python-ast.c
Python/Python-ast.h
Python/symbtable.c
Python/compile.c
```

I'm doing this on Windows, so instead of running `make`, I ran `PCbuild/build.bat`. The build seemed to be successful. However, when I ran the freshly-built `python.exe`, my keyword was not recognized (got `NameError: name [...] is not defined`).

As a sanity test, I tried to remove the break statement from Python by deleting `break_stmt` from `Grammar/Grammar` and rerunning `PCbuild/build.bat`. The break statement worked just fine, which means that the removal has failed.

I've also noticed that the files `Include/graminit.c` and `Include/graminit.h` were not regenerated, and, according to the PEP that I've mentioned, it should have been done by `pgen`, which was supposed to be called by `make`. But as I've mentioned earlier, I ran `PCbuild/build.bat`, and not `make`. I tried to run `pgen` manually, but it failed with the exception `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

So, since the removal of a keyword has also failed, I think that my custom Python was not built properly (even though the build appears to be successful and it generates a working `python.exe`). What might be causing this?

EDIT: I've also tried to delete the file `Grammar/Grammar` and rebuild, and the build still worked. Something's not right.